# Airflow:S3FileTransformOperator:Python Script runs fine in local but NOT in S3FileTransformOperator:Tried different approach

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

**Requirement:** Edit the S3 file for the last row and remove double-quotes and extra pipeline and upload it back the same file back to s3 path

**Operator**

```
     cleanup = S3FileTransformOperator(
                task_id='cleanup', 
                source_s3_key='s3://path/outbound/incoming.txt',
                dest_s3_key='s3://path/outbound/incoming.txt',
                replace=True,
     transform_script='/usr/local/airflow/dags/scripts/clean_up.py'
            )
```

**> Method 1 Approach**

**Issue:** Able to run the python script locally and but while running in Airflow it threw an error as below

**Error :** `cannot mmap an empty file`

Check the below `output readline : b''`

**Log**

```
    [2020-07-07 19:21:20,706] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:115} INFO - Downloading source S3 file s3://path/outbound/incoming.txt
[2020-07-07 19:21:24,224] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:124} INFO - Dumping S3 file s3://path/outbound/incoming.txt contents to local file /tmp/tmp9ihtv1up
[2020-07-07 19:21:59,988] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:145} INFO - Output:
[2020-07-07 19:22:00,183] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - Error in updating the file. Message: cannot mmap an empty file
[2020-07-07 19:22:00,183] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - Starting data cleaning...
[2020-07-07 19:22:00,183] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - input readline : b'"4405348400"|""|""|0|"R"|""|""|""|""|""|""|"23 Main"|"St"|""|""|""|"Holmdel"|"NJ"|"07733"|"N"\n'
[2020-07-07 19:22:00,183] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - b'TR|4826301'
[2020-07-07 19:22:00,183] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - output readline : b''
[2020-07-07 19:22:00,187] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-07-07 19:22:00,187] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO -   File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/scripts/neustar_sid_clean_up.py", line 41, in <module>
[2020-07-07 19:22:00,187] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO -     perform_cleanup(input, output)
[2020-07-07 19:22:00,187] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO -   File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/scripts/neustar_sid_clean_up.py", line 27, in perform_cleanup
[2020-07-07 19:22:00,187] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO -     with closing(mmap.mmap(output.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)) as mm:
[2020-07-07 19:22:00,188] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - ValueError: cannot mmap an empty file
[2020-07-07 19:22:00,497] {__init__.py:1580} ERROR - Transform script failed: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 1436, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/s3_file_transform_operator.py", line 153, in execute
    "Transform script failed: {0}".format(process.returncode)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Transform script failed: 1
```

**Code :**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
from contextlib import closing
import mmap
import sys
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def clnup(input, output):
    try:
        with open(input, 'r+b') as input, open(output, 'r+b') as output:
        print(f'input readline : {input.readline()}')
        with closing(mmap.mmap(input.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)) as mm:
            start_of_line = mm.rfind(b'\n', 0, len(mm) - 1) + 1
            line = mm[start_of_line:].rstrip(b'\r\n')
            last_line = line.decode('utf-8').replace("\"", "")
            last_line = re.sub('[|]*$', '', last_line).encode('utf-8')
            print(last_line)
        print(f'output readline : {output.readline()}')
        with closing(mmap.mmap(output.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)) as mm:
            print(output.readline())
            start_of_line = mm.rfind(b'\n', 0, len(mm) - 1) + 1
        output.seek(start_of_line)  # Move to where old line began
        output.write(last_line)  # Overwrite existing line with new line
        output.truncate()
    except Exception as ex:
            logger.error(f'Error in updating the file. Message: {ex}')
            raise

input = sys.argv[1]
output = sys.argv[2]

print("Starting cleaning...")
perform_cleanup(input, output)
print("Completed cleaning!")
```

**> METHOD 2 Approach**

**Issue :** Have tried running locally with below code and works fine but when running with Airflow it is not working for big file and replaces the file as an empty file

**Log for small file:**

```
[2020-07-07 20:35:37,892] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:115} INFO - Downloading source S3 file s3://path/incoming.2020-07-07.txt
[2020-07-07 20:35:41,981] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:124} INFO - Dumping S3 file s3://path/incoming.2020-07-07.txt contents to local file /tmp/tmp3v_6i1go
[2020-07-07 20:35:42,115] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:145} INFO - Output:
[2020-07-07 20:35:42,293] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - Starting data cleaning...
[2020-07-07 20:35:42,293] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - Completed data cleaning!
[2020-07-07 20:35:42,298] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:158} INFO - Transform script successful. Output temporarily located at /tmp/tmp8uo9t2lk
[2020-07-07 20:35:42,298] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:161} INFO - Uploading transformed file to S3
[2020-07-07 20:35:43,983] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:168} INFO - Upload successful
```

**For big file log :**

```
[2020-07-07 20:25:37,892] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:115} INFO - Downloading source S3 file s3://path/incoming.2020-07-07.txt
[2020-07-07 20:25:52,027] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:124} INFO - Dumping S3 file s3://path/incoming.2020-07-07.txt contents to local file /tmp/tmpgayy9hg9
[2020-07-07 20:26:26,256] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:145} INFO - Output:
[2020-07-07 20:26:29,137] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:158} INFO - Transform script successful. Output temporarily located at /tmp/tmpui1i28r6
[2020-07-07 20:26:29,137] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:161} INFO - Uploading transformed file to S3
```

**Code 2:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
from contextlib import closing
import mmap
import sys
import logging
import os
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
"""
Read the last line of the file and remove the double quotes and extra delimiters
and write back to the file.
"""
def clnup(input, output):
    try:
        with open(input, 'r+b') as myfile:
            with closing(mmap.mmap(myfile.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)) as mm:
                start_of_line = mm.rfind(b'\n', 0, len(mm) - 1) + 1
                line = mm[start_of_line:].rstrip(b'\r\n')
                last_line = line.decode('utf-8').replace("\"", "")
                last_line = re.sub('[|]*$', '', last_line).encode('utf-8')
            myfile.seek(start_of_line)  # Move to where old line began
            myfile.write(last_line)  # Overwrite existing line with new line
            myfile.truncate()
        with open(input, 'r+b') as myfile:
            f = open("temp.txt", "w+b")
            f.write(myfile.read())
        with open("temp.txt", 'r+b') as myfile:
            f = open(output, "w+b")
            f.write(myfile.read())
        os.remove("temp.txt")
    except Exception as ex:
            logger.error(f'Error in updating the file. Message: {ex}')
            raise
input = sys.argv[1]
output = sys.argv[2]
print("Starting data cleaning...")
clnup(input, output)
print("Completed data cleaning!")

(edited)
if you check the log for big file ,below is missing

[2020-07-07 20:35:42,293] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - Starting data cleaning...
[2020-07-07 20:35:42,293] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - Completed data cleaning!
```

**> METHOD Approach 3**

**Issue**: Have tried running locally with below code and works fine but when running with Airflow it replaces the file as an empty file

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
from contextlib import closing
import mmap
import sys
import logging
import os
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

input = sys.argv[1]


def clnup(input):
    try:
        with open(input, 'r+b') as myfile:
            with closing(mmap.mmap(myfile.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)) as mm:
                start_of_line = mm.rfind(b'\n', 0, len(mm) - 1) + 1
                line = mm[start_of_line:].rstrip(b'\r\n')
                last_line = line.decode('utf-8').replace("\"", "")
                last_line = re.sub('[|]*$', '', last_line).encode('utf-8')
            myfile.seek(start_of_line)  # Move to where old line began
            myfile.write(last_line)  # Overwrite existing line with new line
            myfile.truncate()
    except Exception as ex:
            logger.error(f'Error in updating the file. Message: {ex}')
            raise

print("Starting data cleaning...")
clnup(input)
print("Completed data cleaning!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are filling all the memory reading the whole file in a single string.
You have to read one line at the time with `readline` ( without *s* ): it will return an iterator. Loop the iterator and then save it one line at the time.